# For an integral domain $R$, is $S^{-1}(R[x])$ necessarily not a projective $R[x]$ module?

Tags: modules

First, let $K$ be a field. Then the field of rational functions $K(x)$ is a projective $K[x]$ module. I can prove this by showing that $K(x)$ is not a free $K[x]$-module because $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, which means that free implies projective.

My question is, if we were to replace $K$ by an integral domain $R$, could $S^{-1}(R[x])$, the field of fractions of $R[x]$, be a projective $R[x]$-module? Since $R[x]$ is not necessarily a PID, the above strategy would no longer apply.

Comment: What does $R(x)$ mean?  The field of fractions of $R[x]$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: What do you mean by "$R(x),$ the field of fractions of $R[x]$"? $R(x)$ is not a field of fraction of $R[x]$. The field of fraction of $R[x]$ is $Q(R)(x)$ where $Q(R)$ is the field of fractions of $R$.

Comment: OK, what I meant was the set $S^{-1}(R[x])$ where $S=R[x]\setminus \{0\}$. Does this make sense?

Comment: If $S=R[x] \setminus \{0\}$, then $S^{-1}R[x]$ is same as $Q(R)(x)$. You are also inverting non-zero the elements of $R$.

Comment: My apologies. I am not completely familiar with the notation.